# Change the initial size of log files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am changing the initial size of log files but it goes back to its previous size. Can somebody please let me know what do I need to do so that it gets the new size?

Thanks

Comment: What SQL RDBMS are you using MySql, SQL Sever??? What are you changing it to? what size is it going back to ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. I am changing it to 2 GM from 2 MB and it is going back to 2 MB.

Comment: This should probably be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ as it is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: how are you changing the size of the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [My_DB]                   --<-- Your db name
      MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'My_DB_log'  --<-- logical name of the log file
                  , SIZE = 2048 )
GO
```